# TestNG: constant NPE on @AfterMethod

Tags: java, spring, testng

I have randomly failing tests no my CI server.
The problem that I'm getting NullPointerException's within tearDown() method.

The common structure which causes this behavior is simple:

```
@Test
class MyRandomlyFailingTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

  @Autowired
  private SomeSpringBean someSpringBean;

  @BeforeMethod 
  public void beforeMethod() {
    someSpringBean.addTestData("");
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
    someSpringBean.removeTestData("");
  }
}
```

So I have randomly null fields in `@AfterMethod` which were obviously fine when running tests. But somehow it happens that fields are null again.

`@Autowired` is provided by spring 3.2

So I can't find the reason why it happens. Only solution to this is to stop using `@AfterMethod` annotations at all

Comment: Well there is nothing strange here in this tiny tiny snippet of course. Do you have multiple test suites? In my experience randomly failing tests are generally caused by unit tests influencing each other - the order of execution will determine if something fails or not.

Comment: Do you use concurrent threads for test execution? With TestNG you must be very careful when running tests in mulitple concurrent threads, since TestNG's instance lifecycle is different from JUnit's. With TestNG, only one instance of each test class is created and it is reused by all the test methods, possibly even by multiple threads that run different test methods in parallel. 

This also applies to the before and after hooks - these might be run by multiple threads in parallel too.

Comment: @BastianVoigt no, for this group parallel execution is disabled. And other group are plain unit tests without spring. Interesting information regarding testng.